# Can't seem to be able to target nearest div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="outerBox">          
   <div class="innerBox">
        //text
   </div>
   <div class="clickMe">
        <span class="icon"></span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="hiddenDiv">//hidden div</div>
```

I need to be able to show(".hiddenDiv") when I click ".clickMe" but for some reason I cen't seem to be able to target it... Tried all sorts of variations but nothing seem to work. Here's the latest:

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {        
        $(this).parents().closest(".hiddenDiv").show();
});
```

Comment: How about $(".hiddenDiv").show();

Comment: What if there are `.hiddenDiv`s somewhere else on the page? This would show those also. Just needs to be a little more generic.

Comment: Have you tried using `.parent()` or `.closest(".hiddenDiv","body")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {        
    $(this).parent().next(".hiddenDiv").show();
});
```

Or this:

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {        
    $(this).parent().siblings(".hiddenDiv").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.hiddenDiv').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".clickMe").click(function() {        
    $('.hiddenDiv', $(this).parents()).show();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Wpqz4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".clickMe").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".outerBox").next(".hiddenDiv").show();
});
```